# how to install AMD RADEON driver 20.45 into Ubuntu 20.04 for a 6000 series gpu

Tags: drivers, 20.04, software-installation, amdgpu

This page: https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-linux-20-45

says:

> To get support for our latest graphics cards (Radeon RX 6x00 series), here are the components that you will need:
>
> - Kernel 5.10 or newer
> - Mesa 20.2 (or optionally, Oibaf mesa 21.0 from here: [https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers](https://launchpad.net/%7Eoibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers))
> - llvm 11.0 or newer

Well I updated my kernel to `Linux 5.10.12-051012-generic x86_64 GNU/Linux`

I tried to install LLVM by:

1. Adding this to the software update control panel:

   ```
   deb http://apt.llvm.org/focal/ llvm-toolchain-focal-11 main
   ```
2. Adding the gpg key:

   ```
   $ sudo wget -O - https://apt.llvm.org/llvm-snapshot.gpg.key|sudo apt-key add -
   ```
3. updating the cache:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get update
   ```
4. Installed clang, etc with:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install clang-11 clang-tools-11 clang-11-doc libclang-common-11-dev libclang-11-dev libclang1-11 clang-format-11 python-clang-11 clangd-11 lldb-11 lld-11
   ```
5. Got this error:

   ```
   E: Unable to locate package python-clang-11
   ```
6. Checked my version of clang:

   ```
   $ clang --version

   clang version 10.0.0-4ubuntu1 
   Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
   Thread model: posix
   InstalledDir: /usr/bin
   ```
7. Checked my version of LLVM:

   ```
   $ llvm-config --version
   10.0.0
   ```

I dont know why I am at version 10 for clang and LLVM?
I havent got a clue how to install MESA.

Comment: Well this is quite the challenge. To install the Python bit, you'll need to use `sudo apt install python3-clang-11`. To check your clang version, you'll need to use `clang-11 --version`. `llvm-config` is something I can't find in 11, but I can confirm the llvm 11 runtime is installable. I did all of this in a VM to test this, but it does seem incomplete. Ubuntu 20.10 makes a lot of this much simpler, as 11 is the default version for that release, but 20.04 seems to require multiple versions.

Answer (score 1):

Wendell from Level1 Techs forum solved it.

https://forum.level1techs.com/t/ubuntu-20-10-rx-6800-xt-how-to-steam-vulkan-up-and-runing-guide-wip/164137/52